# Building a Simple WebView APP with Javascript in iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, ios6

Ok guys, so I am new to iOS programming.

Im trying to build a VERY SIMPLE WebView iOS App that loads an External URL and all the Javascript (@external server too) associated with it.

The following code loads the page perfectly but when I click on the "Login" button, the Javascript it calls doesnt seem to do anything.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    UIWebView *webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [[self view] addSubview:webView];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsitehere.com/mob/"
                                                       ]]];
}
```

This is the code for the Login button in the external HTML file:

```
<a id="btnLogin" data-role="button" data-icon="star" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnLogin&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><span>Login</span></a>
```

I have also tried using different PhoneGap/Cordova/ChildBrowser tutorials and everything seems very outdated/not working.

If possible, I also need GeoLocation (web page requests current position for certain features).
I basically just need it to work exactly as it does in Safari.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing extensive research, I found out that UIWebView's User-Agent is not properly recognized by ASP.NET. This causes authentication issues with ASP.NET applications.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"User Agent Here", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

After changing the user-agent the authentication process worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode will add any javascript resource files to the **Compile Sources** of your project by default.  They should be removed from this and placed instead in the **Copy Bundle Resources** of your project.  You can find these in the **Build Phases** tab of your Target, when you select the project.  Every time I've had my JS not respond, this has been the cause.